# Jquery slider starts to speed up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on our website and noticed that the slider on the homepage speeds up when the user clicks on the next button.

It slides OK when you don't select the next arrow, but suddenly speeds up when you do.

I think this is what is causing it to speed up:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

setTimeout("$('.caro-arrow.caro-arrow-r').click()", 8000);
$('.caro-arrow.caro-arrow-r').click( function () {
setTimeout("$('.caro-arrow.caro-arrow-r').click()", 8000);
}); 

})
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix it so that it doesn't slide quicker when the next arrow is selected?

Thanks

Comment: You should clear any previously set timeout. But your code doesn't make much sense anyway. Why on clicked element want you to trigger click on this same element after some delay?!

Comment: You are in a recursive infinite loop because when document is ready, you make a trigger in click that is listening with another trigger. It's infinite. Remove the first setTimeout and let the second inside the click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the setTimeout

```
    var clears='';
    setInterval("$('.caro-arrow.caro-arrow-r').click()", 8000);
    $('.caro-arrow.caro-arrow-r').click( function () {
    clearTimeout(clears);
    clears = setTimeout(function(){changeSliderFunction()/*call change slider image function*/}, 8000);
    });
```

when user click the arrow click start time executed if user click continously then setTimeout execute many times and it increases slider speed

Comment: It sounds like anyway OP would have better to use an interval instead and not trigger a click event but calling a referenced function

Comment: I tried the above code, It seems to stop the speeding up issue, however the slider stops sliding automatically on page load now